# Split column values from c(a,b) to a and b in R data frame

Tags: r, position, substring

I want to find the different positions of a text within a substring. Say I have the data frame as below:

```
Key String
10  09123022130908123
11  01230012780981093
12  12387109387126309
```

Not sure how to put this in a table form here, but the idea is each key has a long string of numbers. To find the location of the text '09' in each string, I used the code:

```
df$try<-gregexpr(pattern ='09',df$string)
```

This gave me the table as

```
Key String            try
10  09123022130908123 c(1,11)
11  01230012780981093 c(11,15)
12  12387109387126309 c(7,16)
```

Now I want pure numbers in different columns rather than a single column containing c(a,b). How can I split such values into a and b under different columns?
Any other suggestion to get all the positions of the required text within a substring are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: you probably want the `unlist` function wrapped in some kind of an `apply` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not super beautiful but working. First your data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  key = c(10,11,12,13),
  string = c( 
    "09123022130908123",
    "01230012780981093",
    "12387109387126309",
    "88888888888888809" 
  )
)
```

I use here `lapply` and a `function`, `whichmatch` gives you the first, second, etc. match

```
searchString <- function( string, whichmatch) {
    x <- unlist(gregexpr(pattern ='09', string ))[whichmatch]
    return(x)
} 
df$a <- lapply( df$string, FUN = function(x) { searchString( x, 1 ) })
df$b <- lapply( df$string, FUN = function(x) { searchString( x, 2 ) })
rm(searchString)

  key            string  a  b
1  10 09123022130908123  1 11
2  11 01230012780981093 11 15
3  12 12387109387126309  7 16
4  13 88888888888888809 16 NA
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. But this is not working as expected. Its throwing a column full of same values, which corresponds to [whichmatch] value from the entire column of 'string'. I think this is because of cases where I have single digit numbers, i.e, instead of 2 finds, the pattern is present only once and gregexpr() gives a proper number.

Comment: Can you maybe post some code? Or the head of your data? Cause the function should return NA if you have just one match (I'm gonna amend the example here).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a ton Richard and z-cool!
I ended up using z-cool's function.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `gregexpr`.  But you'll need to cycle through your `gregexpr` results and make the matches the same length, filling the empty values with `NA`. With `df` (posted below), you could do

```
g <- gregexpr("09", df$string, fixed = TRUE)
cbind(df, t(sapply(g, `length<-`, max(sapply(g, length)))))
#   key            string  1  2
# 1  10 09123022130908123  1 11
# 2  11 01230012780981093 11 15
# 3  12 12387109387126309  7 16
# 4  13 88888888888888809 16 NA
```

In case you're doing this over multiple patterns, here's a little function that might help

```
where <- function(data, col, pattern, ...) 
{
    g <- gregexpr(pattern, data[[col]], ...)
    dc <- do.call(rbind, lapply(g, function(x) {
        x <- if(any(x < 0)) NA else x
        `length<-`(x, max(sapply(g, length)))
    }))
    colnames(dc) <- letters[1:ncol(dc)]
    cbind(df, dc)
}
```

And a few sample runs:

```
where(df, "string", "8", fixed = TRUE)
#   key            string  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o
# 1  10 09123022130908123 14 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 2  11 01230012780981093 10 13 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 3  12 12387109387126309  4 10 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
# 4  13 88888888888888809  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
where(df, "string", "09", fixed = TRUE)
#   key            string  a  b
# 1  10 09123022130908123  1 11
# 2  11 01230012780981093 11 15
# 3  12 12387109387126309  7 16
# 4  13 88888888888888809 16 NA
where(df, "string", "12", fixed = TRUE)
#   key            string  a  b
# 1  10 09123022130908123  3 15
# 2  11 01230012780981093  2  7
# 3  12 12387109387126309  1 12
# 4  13 88888888888888809 NA NA
```

**Data :**

```
df <- 
structure(list(key = c(10, 11, 12, 13), string = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("01230012780981093", "09123022130908123", 
"12387109387126309", "88888888888888809"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("key", 
"string"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```